# How do i make a fit tablayout in every screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have made a design for `TabLayout`, but I can't make the size fit with 2 different screens. I use two different screens like tablet and android phone.

**How can I fix it?**

---

This is my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.inducesmile.androidmusicplayer
    .fragment.LibraryFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorMaroon">

        <ImageView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="102dp"
             android:src="@drawable/logo1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorMaroon"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorGold"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/custTab"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorGold"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

I want to make 4 menu/fragments with `TabLayout` for the details, my XML was worked but the problem is the size not optimize if I run in tablet screen.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the layout responsive in order to view it in tablet, mobile or any other android based mobile. To make the layout responsive, we use Constraint Layout.